# reactive radioButtons with tooltipBS in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinybs

I want to create a `radioButtons` widget with tooltip using `shinyBS`. What I want to achieve is to create one widget with 3 buttons with different info in `tooltip`. Based on this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34980348/reactive-tooltipbs-in-shiny-using-shinybs)  it was created 3 separate radio buttons with different id values. 
Is it possible to do the same thing but with one radio widget with 3 buttons (i.e. with one id value)?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)

ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
      column(3,
             HTML("<div class='container'><br>
                  <h1>Test</h1>
                  <div>
                  <label id='radio_venue_1'> 
                  <input type='radio' value='1' role='button'> button 1 
                  </label>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                  <label id='radio_venue_2'>
                  <input type='radio' value='2' role='button'> button 2
                  </label>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                  <label id='radio_venue_3'>
                  <input type='radio' value='3' role='button'> button 3
                  </label>
                  </div>
                  </div>")), 
      bsTooltip(id = "radio_venue_1", title = "Button 1 Explanation", placement = "right", trigger = "hover"),
      bsTooltip(id = "radio_venue_2", title = "Button 2 Explanation", placement = "right", trigger = "hover"),
      bsTooltip(id = "radio_venue_3", title = "Button 3 Explanation", placement = "right", trigger = "hover"),
      column(9,'Plot')
      )
    )
  )

server <- function(input, output, session) {}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Added the feature for `selectInput`. But there had to be quite some changes to make...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### **Initial answer: Creating tooltips for radioButtons**

Late answer, but here it goes:

As you have seen, shinyBS's tooltip function is only designed for selection by id. You want something much finer than that, so we need to construct some new function to replace the coarser `bsTooltip`.

The new function is called `radioTooltip` and is basically a ripoff from `bsTooltip`. It takes one more arguement, namely the `choice` of the `radioButton` you want the tooltip to be assigned to. This allows for finer selection. The difference is now the way the element is selected on the document. Without going too much into JavaScript details, we select the element with given Id and holding the supplied `radioButton` `choice` (the internal one, so the value you'd get with `input$radioButtonId`).

Code below. I suggest you try it out.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)

radioTooltip <- function(id, choice, title, placement = "bottom", trigger = "hover", options = NULL){

  options = shinyBS:::buildTooltipOrPopoverOptionsList(title, placement, trigger, options)
  options = paste0("{'", paste(names(options), options, sep = "': '", collapse = "', '"), "'}")
  bsTag <- shiny::tags$script(shiny::HTML(paste0("
    $(document).ready(function() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        $('input', $('#", id, "')).each(function(){
          if(this.getAttribute('value') == '", choice, "') {
            opts = $.extend(", options, ", {html: true});
            $(this.parentElement).tooltip('destroy');
            $(this.parentElement).tooltip(opts);
          }
        })
      }, 500)
    });
  ")))
  htmltools::attachDependencies(bsTag, shinyBS:::shinyBSDep)
}

ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
      column(3,
        radioButtons("radioSelection", label = "So many options!", choices = c("A", "B", "C"))
      ),
      radioTooltip(id = "radioSelection", choice = "A", title = "Button 1 Explanation", placement = "right", trigger = "hover"),
      radioTooltip(id = "radioSelection", choice = "B", title = "Button 2 Explanation", placement = "right", trigger = "hover"),
      radioTooltip(id = "radioSelection", choice = "C", title = "Button 3 Explanation", placement = "right", trigger = "hover"),
      column(9,'Plot')
      )
    )
  )

server <- function(input, output, session) {}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Have fun!

### **Edit: Creating tooltips for selectInput/selectizeInput**

For `selectInput` one cannot just change a bit, but there has to be a whole new function. There is mainly one reason. While `radioButtons` have all their choices plainly visible and right there, `selectizeInput` moves the choices around, renders them anew, renders them only when they are first shown and so on. A lot of things happen. This is why this solution grabs the surrounding `div` and listens constantly to `childNodes` being added. The rest is just (hopefully efficient) filtering.

Example Code below:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)

selectizeTooltip <- function(id, choice, title, placement = "bottom", trigger = "hover", options = NULL){

  options = shinyBS:::buildTooltipOrPopoverOptionsList(title, placement, trigger, options)
  options = paste0("{'", paste(names(options), options, sep = "': '", collapse = "', '"), "'}")
  bsTag <- shiny::tags$script(shiny::HTML(paste0("
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var opts = $.extend(", options, ", {html: true});
      var selectizeParent = document.getElementById('", id, "').parentElement;
      var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
        mutations.forEach(function(mutation){
          $(mutation.addedNodes).filter('div').filter(function(){return(this.getAttribute('data-value') == '", choice, "');}).each(function() {
            $(this).tooltip('destroy');
            $(this).tooltip(opts);
          });
        });
      });
      observer.observe(selectizeParent, { subtree: true, childList: true });
    });
  ")))
  htmltools::attachDependencies(bsTag, shinyBS:::shinyBSDep)
}

ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    actionButton("but", "Change choices!"),
    selectizeInput(inputId = "lala", label = "Label!", choices = LETTERS),
    selectizeTooltip(id = "lala", choice = "c", title = "Tooltip for c", placement = "right"),
    selectizeTooltip(id = "lala", choice = "C", title = "Tooltip for C", placement = "right"),
    selectizeTooltip(id = "lala", choice = "F", title = "Tooltip for F", placement = "right")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  observeEvent(input$but, {
    updateSelectizeInput(session, "lala", choices = c("C", letters))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Note that the tooltips also survive `updateSelectizeInput` and there can be tooltips for choices that initially don't exist.

If people are interested, I could send a feature request to the shinyBS guys to possibly include this into their work.

Comment: Thanks! I think it will be great if they include them. Good job! PS.radioTooltip() fun. also works well on checkboxGroupInput() so maybe you should propose different name for it.

Comment: Did the request here: https://github.com/ebailey78/shinyBS/pull/70 . Lets see how it goes.

Answer (score 3):

You can use jQuery to add an `id` attribute to the radio buttons:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)

js <- '$("#radioSelection :input").each(function() {
    $(this).attr("id", "radio_" + $(this).val());
});'

ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
      column(3,
             radioButtons("radioSelection", label = "So many options!", choices = c("A", "B", "C"))
      ),
      tags$script(js),
      bsTooltip("radio_A", title="Tooltip for A"),
      bsTooltip("radio_B", title="Tooltip for B"),
      bsTooltip("radio_C", title="Tooltip for C"),
      column(9,'Plot')
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server), launch.browser = TRUE)
```