# Shiny: selectizeInput tooltip hover for each choice

Tags: r, shiny, tooltip, selectize.js, shinybs

I want the user to see a different tooltip when hovering over grouped choices in selectizeInput. This was solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36132204/reactive-radiobuttons-with-tooltipbs-in-shiny/37165597#37165597) for a flat vector of choices. i.e. `choices = c("a", "b", "c", "d")`. The difference is I would like this to work for a nested list of inputs, i.e. `choices = list(`first`= c("a", "b"),`second `= c("c", "d"))`

Here is an example that works for a flat vector of choices:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)

selectizeTooltip <- function(id, choice, title, placement = "bottom", trigger = "hover", options = NULL){
  
  options = shinyBS:::buildTooltipOrPopoverOptionsList(title, placement, trigger, options)
  options = paste0("{'", paste(names(options), options, sep = "': '", collapse = "', '"), "'}")
  bsTag <- shiny::tags$script(shiny::HTML(paste0("
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var opts = $.extend(", options, ", {html: true});
      var selectizeParent = document.getElementById('", id, "').parentElement;
      var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
        mutations.forEach(function(mutation){
          $(mutation.addedNodes).filter('div').filter(function(){return(this.getAttribute('data-value') == '", choice, "');}).each(function() {
            $(this).tooltip('destroy');
            $(this).tooltip(opts);
          });
        });
      });
      observer.observe(selectizeParent, { subtree: true, childList: true });
    });
  ")))
  htmltools::attachDependencies(bsTag, shinyBS:::shinyBSDep)
}

ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    selectizeInput(inputId = "lala", label = "Label!", choices = c("a", "b", "c", "d")), # This changes in second example
    selectizeTooltip(id = "lala", choice = "a", title = "Tooltip for a", placement = "right"),
    selectizeTooltip(id = "lala", choice = "b", title = "Tooltip for b", placement = "right"),
    selectizeTooltip(id = "lala", choice = "c", title = "Tooltip for c", placement = "right"), 
    selectizeTooltip(id = "lala", choice = "d", title = "Tooltip for d", placement = "right")
    
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  observeEvent(input$lala,{
    print(input$lala)
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Here is the example that I want to get working

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)


selectizeTooltip <- function(id, choice, title, placement = "bottom", trigger = "hover", options = NULL){
  

  options = shinyBS:::buildTooltipOrPopoverOptionsList(title, placement, trigger, options)
  options = paste0("{'", paste(names(options), options, sep = "': '", collapse = "', '"), "'}")
  bsTag <- shiny::tags$script(shiny::HTML(paste0("
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var opts = $.extend(", options, ", {html: true});
      var selectizeParent = document.getElementById('", id, "').parentElement;
      var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
        mutations.forEach(function(mutation){
          $(mutation.addedNodes).filter('div').filter(function(){return(this.getAttribute('data-value') == '", choice, "');}).each(function() {
            $(this).tooltip('destroy');
            $(this).tooltip(opts);
          });
        });
      });
      observer.observe(selectizeParent, { subtree: true, childList: true });
    });
  ")))
  htmltools::attachDependencies(bsTag, shinyBS:::shinyBSDep)
}

ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    selectizeInput(inputId = "lala", label = "Label!", choices = list(`first` = c("a", "b"), 
                                                                      `second` = c("c", "d"))), # this is different
    selectizeTooltip(id = "lala", choice = "a", title = "Tooltip for a", placement = "right"),
    selectizeTooltip(id = "lala", choice = "b", title = "Tooltip for b", placement = "right"),
    selectizeTooltip(id = "lala", choice = "c", title = "Tooltip for c", placement = "right"), 
    selectizeTooltip(id = "lala", choice = "d", title = "Tooltip for d", placement = "right")
    
    # selectizeTooltip(id = "lala", choice = "first.a", title = "Tooltip for a", placement = "right"),
    # selectizeTooltip(id = "lala", choice = "first.b", title = "Tooltip for b", placement = "right"),
    # selectizeTooltip(id = "lala", choice = "second.c", title = "Tooltip for c", placement = "right"), 
    # selectizeTooltip(id = "lala", choice = "second.d", title = "Tooltip for d", placement = "right")
    
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  observeEvent(input$lala,{
    print(input$lala)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I tried changing my choice to be id.choice (first.a) for example with no luck. I also tried [bsTooltip](https://ebailey78.github.io/shinyBS/docs/Tooltips_and_Popovers.html) with no luck. It appears that this function only allows you to have one tooltip whereas I need a tooltip for each choice in the selectizeInput.

I am open to different solutions like changing the structure of the choices in selectizeInput or using a different selector input, though I would like to be able to have groups of choices in any case. Or modifying the JS portion so it will recognize what I am looking for.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way.

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectizeInput(
    inputId = "sel",
    label = "Animals",
    choices = NULL,
    options = list(
      options = list(
        list( species = 'mammal', value = "dog", name = "Dog"),
        list( species = 'mammal', value = "cat", name = "Cat"),
        list( species = 'mammal', value = "horse", name = "Horse"),
        list( species = 'mammal', value = "kangaroo", name = "Kangaroo"),
        list( species = 'bird', value = 'duck', name = 'Duck'),
        list( species = 'bird', value = 'chicken', name = 'Chicken'),
        list( species = 'bird', value = 'ostrich', name = 'Ostrich'),
        list( species = 'bird', value = 'seagull', name = 'Seagull'),
        list( species = 'reptile', value = 'snake', name = 'Snake'),
        list( species = 'reptile', value = 'lizard', name = 'Lizard'),
        list( species = 'reptile', value = 'alligator', name = 'Alligator'),
        list( species = 'reptile', value = 'turtle', name = 'Turtle')
      ),
      optgroups = list(
        list( value = 'mammal',  label = 'Mammal',  tooltip = 'Mammalia'),
        list( value = 'bird',    label = 'Bird',    tooltip = 'Aves'),
        list( value = 'reptile', label = 'Reptile', tooltip = 'Reptilia')
      ),
      optgroupField = "species",
      labelField = "name",
      render = I(
        "{optgroup_header: function(data, escape) {
            return '<div class=\"optgroup-header\"><span title=\"' + data.tooltip + '\">' + escape(data.label) + '</span></div>';
          }
        }"
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

---

## Edit: customized tooltips

[image]

```r
library(shiny)
library(bslib)

css <- '
.tooltip {
  pointer-events: none;
}
.tooltip > .tooltip-inner {
  pointer-events: none;
  background-color: #73AD21;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 8px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-style: italic;
  text-align: justify;
  margin-left: 0;
  max-width: 1000px;
}
.tooltip > .arrow::before {
  border-right-color: #73AD21;
}
'

js <- "
function () {
  setTimeout(function(){$('[data-toggle=tooltip]').tooltip();}, 100);
}
"

ui <- fluidPage(
  theme = bs_theme(version = 4),
  tags$head(tags$style(HTML(css))),
  
  selectizeInput(
    inputId = "sel",
    label = "Animals",
    choices = NULL,
    options = list(
      options = list(
        list( species = 'mammal', value = "dog", name = "Dog"),
        list( species = 'mammal', value = "cat", name = "Cat"),
        list( species = 'mammal', value = "horse", name = "Horse"),
        list( species = 'mammal', value = "kangaroo", name = "Kangaroo"),
        list( species = 'bird', value = 'duck', name = 'Duck'),
        list( species = 'bird', value = 'chicken', name = 'Chicken'),
        list( species = 'bird', value = 'ostrich', name = 'Ostrich'),
        list( species = 'bird', value = 'seagull', name = 'Seagull'),
        list( species = 'reptile', value = 'snake', name = 'Snake'),
        list( species = 'reptile', value = 'lizard', name = 'Lizard'),
        list( species = 'reptile', value = 'alligator', name = 'Alligator'),
        list( species = 'reptile', value = 'turtle', name = 'Turtle')
      ),
      optgroups = list(
        list( value = 'mammal',  label = 'Mammal',  tooltip = 'Mammalia'),
        list( value = 'bird',    label = 'Bird',    tooltip = 'Aves'),
        list( value = 'reptile', label = 'Reptile', tooltip = 'Reptilia')
      ),
      optgroupField = "species",
      labelField = "name",
      render = I(
        "{optgroup_header: function(data, escape) {
            return '<div class=\"optgroup-header\"><span data-toggle=\"tooltip\" data-placement=\"right\" title=\"' + data.tooltip + '\">' + escape(data.label) + '</span></div>';
          }
        }"
      ),
      onDropdownOpen = I(js)
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

---

## Edit

If you also want tooltips for the options, add a `tooltip` field in the list of options, and add a field `option` in the `render` option (see at the end):

```r
      options = list(
        list( species = 'mammal', value = "dog", name = "Dog", tooltip = "it is a pet"),
        ......,
      ),
      optgroups = list(
        list( value = 'mammal',  label = 'Mammal',  tooltip = 'Mammalia'),
        list( value = 'bird',    label = 'Bird',    tooltip = 'Aves'),
        list( value = 'reptile', label = 'Reptile', tooltip = 'Reptilia')
      ),
      optgroupField = "species",
      labelField = "name",
      render = I(
        "{
          optgroup_header: function(data, escape) {
            return '<div class=\"optgroup-header\"><span title=\"' + data.tooltip + '\">' + escape(data.label) + '</span></div>';
          },
          option: function(data, escape) {
            return '<div><span title=\"' + data.tooltip + '\">' + escape(data.name) + '</span></div>';
          }
        }"
      )
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks! Is there a way to get it show a tooltip for the animal as well (dog, cat, horse, etc) as opposed ot just the group header (mammal, bird, reptile)?

Comment: @NateHawkins Yes, see my latest edit. I also fixed a mistake by the way.

Comment: Okay now I'm seeing the tooltip but not the actual name of the animal. Dog, cat, horse, etc are all undefined, undefined, undefined. The tooltip is showing up though. Is that an issue with the 2nd function in render?

Comment: @NateHawkins Ah sorry it's `data.name`, not `data.label`. I fix.

Comment: @NateHawkins You're welcome. Please upvote and accept the answer. It took me a couple of hours.