# shinydashboard tooltip on hover over sidebar toggle

Tags: javascript, html, css, r, shiny

wanting to create a tooltip on hover of the sidebar toggle of a shinydashboard page. Currently got the background of the css element colour changing on hover, just need a tooltip. Maybe some javascript?

Reprex:

```
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    
    
    tags$head(
      tags$style(
        "
        .skin-blue .main-header .navbar .sidebar-toggle:hover {
        background-color: red;
        
        }
        "
      ),
    )
    
  )
)


server <- function(input, output){
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Thanks!

Comment: The `shinyBS` package provides this functionality.  See [here](https://ebailey78.github.io/shinyBS/docs/Tooltips_and_Popovers.html),

Comment: Came across that, but unsure of how to apply it to a CSS element. The `id` input for the `shinyBS` package is a Shiny input$id. Maybe I'm missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either go with the `shinyBS`  provided in the comments or use javascript.

If you would like to approach this with javascript than you need to insert `tags$script` and inside the following code

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
          $(".sidebar-toggle").attr("data-toggle", "tooltip");
          $(".sidebar-toggle").attr("data-placement", "bottom");
          $(".sidebar-toggle").attr("title", "Toggle Sidebar");
          $("[data-toggle=\'tooltip\']").tooltip();
          
          $(".sidebar-toggle").click(function(){
            $("body").toggleClass("sidebar-collapse");
            $(this).tooltip("hide");
          });
        });
        '
```

Remember if you are doing javascript you first need to inspect the html elements in order to address them with JS.
[image]

So the whole code looks like this

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    tags$head(
      tags$style(
        "
        .skin-blue .main-header .navbar .sidebar-toggle:hover {
          background-color: red;
        }
        "
      ),
      tags$script(
        '
        $(document).ready(function(){
          $(".sidebar-toggle").attr("data-toggle", "tooltip");
          $(".sidebar-toggle").attr("data-placement", "bottom");
          $(".sidebar-toggle").attr("title", "Sidebar hover");
          $("[data-toggle=\'tooltip\']").tooltip();
          
          $(".sidebar-toggle").click(function(){
            $("body").toggleClass("sidebar-collapse");
            $(this).tooltip("hide");
          });
        });
        '
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output){}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

And output like this

[image]

For more see also this: [Shiny: selectizeInput tooltip hover for each choice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76213431/shiny-selectizeinput-tooltip-hover-for-each-choice)

Comment: that's perfect thank you! Is there a way to add css to the class? Setting the `background-color` to a different colour adds a background to the padding, but not the curved tooltip itself. This is referenced by adding in:  `tags$head( tags$style(HTML(' .tooltip{background-color: yellow}')))`. The background colour was just a test, I want to reduce the opacity of the tooltip. Thanks!

Comment: Additionally, the tooltip doesn't hide after clicking the button, and then hovering over it again. I wish I knew JavaScript to fix this up, just sounds like a logic issue. Let me know if you have any solutions! Thanks :)