# Dynamic popover or tooltip in shinyBS

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, shinybs

**The idea**

I have a `box()` in a shiny app. The `box()` includes a `title` argument (which in turn includes an `icon`) and a `selectInput()`element. On hoover over the `icon` I wanted to have a tooltip (using `tipify()`) or a popover (using  `popify()`) which `title` or `content` argument (or both) would be generated depending on `selectInput()` input.

**The problem**

Neither `tipify()` nor `popify()` correcctly implement `textOutput()` as their `title` or `content` argument. They need a character string so I tried to use a `reactiveValues()` element as a function argument but it also failed.

**The question**

Can tooltip or popover content be made dynamic by just using `r`? How could this be done?

I suspect it can be done with `JavaScript` but I have little knowledge of it.

**The code**

Attempt 1 - failed - displays code not actual text

```
library("shiny")
library("shinydashboard")
library("shinyBS")

ui <- fluidPage(
 box(
   title = span("My box",
                tipify(el = icon(name = "info-circle", lib = "font-awesome"), title = textOutput("TIP"))),
   selectInput(
     inputId = "SELECT",
     label = NULL,
     choices = c("Option1" = "Option1",
                 "Option2" = "Option2"
     ),
     multiple = FALSE
   )
 )
)
server <- function(input, output, session){
  output$TIP <- renderText({"Helo world!"})
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Attempt 2 - failed - cannot create UI as TIP (`reactiveValues()`) is not yet defined

```
library("shiny")
library("shinydashboard")
library("shinyBS")

ui <- fluidPage(
 box(
   title = span("My box",
                tipify(el = icon(name = "info-circle", lib = "font-awesome"), title = TIP$a)),
   selectInput(
     inputId = "SELECT",
     label = NULL,
     choices = c("Option1" = "Option1",
                 "Option2" = "Option2"
     ),
     multiple = FALSE
   )
 )
)
server <- function(input, output, session){
  TIP <- reactiveValues(a = "Hello world!")
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34980348/reactive-tooltipbs-in-shiny-using-shinybs) is a similar question but it does not solve the problem described here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What could be done is creating the title entirely in the server side. This way you have no problem making it dynamic. This could give you this kind of app:

```
library("shiny")
library("shinydashboard")
library("shinyBS")

ui <- fluidPage(
  box(
    title = uiOutput("title"),
    selectInput(
      inputId = "SELECT",
      label = NULL,
      choices = c("Option1" = "Option1",
                  "Option2" = "Option2"
      ),
      multiple = FALSE
    )
  )
)
server <- function(input, output, session){
  TIP <- reactiveValues()
  observe({
    TIP$a <- ifelse(input$SELECT =="Option1","Hello World","Hello Mars")
  })


  output$title <- renderUI({span("My box",
                   tipify(el = icon(name = "info-circle", lib = "font-awesome"), title = TIP$a))})


}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Its strange but if you choise option1 and look at tooltip and then change on option2 nothing showing in toolip ( may be it is only in my R)

Comment: You have to wait for a while as the update is done with an `observe({})`. But it definitly work in my R. Could you retry and confirm plz?

Comment: The code does work and thus is a solution to the problem. Indeed it is relatively slow, which still leaves room for improvement. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I don't know if you can improve it a lot. If you make the icon dynamic `icon(name = ifelse(input$SELECT =="Option1","info-circle","ban")`, the result is almost instant. It seems that the text have more trouble being updated quickly.